# Is Visual Studio C++ interpreted like C#?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

Are assemblies compiled by Visual Studio .NET for C++ projects interpreted code like C# is? (Hence easily de-compiled back into their full source code by the many tools out there)

Comment: What makes you think C# is interpreted? Yes, a bytecode-like intermediate language is distributed to end users, but the .Net assemblies are compiled before execution.

Comment: perhaps 'interpreted' is the wrong term? Its not like the machine code which is virtually impossible to decompile which I guess the classic c++ linkers produced, but instead some file of instructions which can be decompiled back, or is it?

Comment: When you run a decompiler on a C# assembly, it's looking at the intermediate language from before the program is invoked and just-in-time compiled. What you get after the Just-In-Time compiler runs is almost exactly like C++ machine code. And FWIW, you can compiler "regular" dll or exe files as well, it's just a bit harder.

Comment: Mixed-mode assemblies produced by C++/CLI (not C++) can contain both IL and machine code.  It is all machine code once the jitter is done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to answer the question you meant to ask:

If you compile C++ code with `/clr`, then the compiler will produce MSIL instead of machine code, as well as .NET metadata describing your program structure.  That's enough for a disassembler to produce editable C#<sup>1</sup> code that does the same thing.

If you have ordinary C++ code in a C++/CLI project (so you need `/clr`) you can still use `#pragma managed(off)` to make parts of your program compile to (less reversible) machine code.  Only the parts that aren't actually using .NET, though.

---

1. Or C++/CLI... but the MSIL -> C++/CLI converter in .NET Reflector is quite buggy, and I assume the same is true for other decompilers, if they even try to support it.

Answer (score 2):

C# is not interpreted.

Also notice that compiling from C# - or any other language - to IL should be see as a one way trip. You **can** decompile an assembly into IL and try to translate it back to C#. As Ben and Trant pointed out in the comments, some of the original code may reappear the resulting code, but the more features of the language you use, the more the resulting code will differ from the original.

Comment: It will be different from the original code.  How different depends on what language features the original code utilized.  For much code, the decompilation result isn't far off the original at all -- in some cases the only difference might be stripping out comments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I have seen for myself where I build a C# project into an exe file, and then feed that exe into a tool such as .NET Reflector or Salamander and out comes my full source code minus comments. I was just wondering is it the same for their c++ projects.

Comment: Also, I think it's fair to describe the decompilation result as "full source code", even if not "original source code".  Full, because it's everything you need to hand the compiler to get a working executable.

Comment: @Trant: Try using some lambdas or LINQ syntax, or a mixture of `while`, `for`, and `do-while` loops... you won't get the exact same thing back from a decompiler.  Also if you're decompiling a release build, all the local variable names will be gone.

Comment: Wow. I had never seen that. All my disassemblies always turned into pretty illegible things, and I don't use any obfuscator. But then again, it's been ages since I last took a look at a disassembly. I'm updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also: iterator and using blocks, anonymous types, type/collection initializers can all cause some significant differences in the result from the original.